# MySQL: REGEXP pattern not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset with a pattern of data as follows:

```
**ColumnName**
a/b
a/b:1
a/b:2
a/b.100
a/b.200
a/b:20
```

I need to write a query with REGEXP such that it fetches only the exact data from the column and not the similar pattern. But, if there is a dot(.) in the value, it should be fetched at the parent pattern.

Here are the scenarios for the dataset above:

```
No.     PATTERN        RESULT
1       "a/b"           a/b
                      a/b.100
                      a/b.200
2       "a/b:1"        a/b:1
3       "a/b:2"        a/b:2 (and not a/b:20)
4       "a/b:20"       a/b:20
```

So far, the query I use follows the pattern 1,2 & 4, but it fails pattern 3. I get both the results in that, including the one which should not be selected, as displayed above.

Following is the query I use to do it:

```
select * from table 
where (ColumnName REGEXP '<Pattern>$' or ColumnName REGEXP '<Pattern>[.^0-9]+');
```

What can I do to this query to make sure that it follows all the scenarios in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.  I think breaking the patterns on a `.` does what you want:

```
where substring_index(col, '.', 1) = v_pattern
```

If the pattern might contain a `'.'` you might want:

```
where (substring_index(col, '.', 1) = v_pattern or
       col = v_pattern
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

compare the substring of ColumnName till '.' with the pattern and also use a strict comparison of the ColumnName with pattern